# Batch insert only unique records into PostgreSQL with Python (millions of records per day)

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have 10M+ records per day to insert into a Postgres database.

90% are duplicates and only the unique records should be inserted (this can be checked on a specific column value).

Because of the large volume, batch inserts seems like the only sensible option.

I'm trying to figure out how to make this work.

**I've tried:**

1. SQLAlchemy, but it throws an error. So I assume it's not possible.

```
s = Session(bind=engine)
s.bulk_insert_mappings(Model, rows)
s.commit()
```

Throws:

```
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "..._key"
```

2. Panda's `to_sql` doesn't have this unique record capability.

So I'm thinking of putting new records in an "intermediate table", then running background jobs in parallel to add those records to the main table if they don't already exist. I don't know if this is the most efficient procedure.

Is there a better approach?
Is there some way to make SQLAlchemy or Pandas do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common ways to go about solving this problem. To pick between these, you need to examine where you're willing to spend the compute power, and whether or not the extra network transfer is going to be an issue. We don't have enough information to make that judgement call for you.

**Option 1:** Load to a temporary table

This option is basically what you described. Have a temporary table or a table that's dedicated to the load, which matches the schema of your destination table. Obviously this should exclude the unique constraints.

Load the entirety of your batch into this table, and once it's all there insert from this table into your destination table. You can very easily use standard SQL statements to do any kind of manipulation you need, such as `distinct` or whether it's the first record, or whatever else.

**Option 2:** Only load unique values, filtering with pandas

Pandas has a [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html?highlight=drop_duplicates) function which limit your dataframe to unique entries, and you can specify things such as which columns to check and which row to keep.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["Age"])
```